# PCI kernel module cannot read BAR

Tags: embedded-linux, pci

I write my  pci driver for custom board on a PowerPC processor (p2020). I use X520 ehternet adapter for testing. When I compile it for x86, it works fine, but when I compile it for my custom board, it reads only 0xffffffff on all BARs.
Here is my code:

```
printk(KERN_INFO "sol probe\r\n");

bar_mask = pci_select_bars(dev, IORESOURCE_MEM_64);
printk("bar_mask 0x%08x PCI_NUM_RESOURCES %d\r\n", bar_mask, PCI_NUM_RESOURCES);

mmio_base = pci_resource_start( dev, bar_num );
mmio_size = pci_resource_len( dev, bar_num );
printk("sol dev BAR%i address = %lx, len = %lx\n", bar_num, mmio_base, mmio_size);

/*
if(pci_enable_msi(dev)){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Cannot enable MSI\r\n");
}
*/

if(pci_user_write_config_word(dev, 0x04, 0x0000)){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Cannot write command config\r\n");
}

if(pci_user_write_config_byte(dev, 0x0c, 0x0000)){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Cannot write cache line size config  config\r\n");
}

read_config32(dev, 0, 0x3c);

if(pci_request_region(dev, bar_num, SOL_DRV_NAME)){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "I/O resource busy\r\n");
        return -EBUSY;
}

if(pci_enable_device(dev)){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Cannot enable memory space access!\r\n");
    return ENODEV;
}

iomap = pci_iomap(dev, bar_num, 0);
if ( !iomap  )
{   
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Cannot IO map at PCI BAR%i!\n", bar_num);
        return -ENOSPC;
}

ret = pci_resource_flags(dev, bar_num);
printk(KERN_ALERT "flags 0x%x08\n", ret);
if(!(ret & IORESOURCE_MEM)){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "IORESORCE_MEM flag isn't seti\n");
}
read_bars(0xf);
return 0;
```

read BAR

```
static void read_bars(unsigned int n){
unsigned long i;
printk(KERN_INFO "iomap\t0x%08x\r\n", (u32)iomap);
for(i = 0; i < (n  << 2); i+=4){
    printk(KERN_INFO "bar 0x%08lx\t: 0x%08x\r\n",\
        i, readl(iomap+i));
}
```

Comment: One possible cause of this is if it hasn't set bit 1 of the command register (Memory Access Enable). (It looks like MAE should be set by pci_enable_device, but I suggest you read back the command register to make sure bit 1 is 1.)

Comment: X520 command register (offset 0x04 ) 0x0002, memory access enable. I read back it after pci_enable_device(dev)

Answer (score 0):

Register ranges for pcie0 in dts was incorrect. After correting, it works.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Can you explain this answer a little more? What is dts, and what register ranges were incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You could read about Device tree usage (dts) [here](https://elinux.org/Device_Tree_Usage)

I had wrong parameter "ranges". It describes addreses for mapping PCI BAR memory space into CPU memory space. My patch is

```
<       ranges = <0x2000000 0x0 0xc0000000 0 0xc0000000 0x0 0x20000000
<             0x1000000 0x0 0x00000000 0 0xffc20000 0x0 0x10000>;
>       ranges = <0x2000000 0x0 0xe0000000 0 0x80000000 0x0 0x20000000
>             0x1000000 0x0 0x00000000 0 0xffc00000 0x0 0x10000>;
```